# How to Supporting Multiple Screens dimension

Tags: android, xml, layout, multiscreen

I am using multi support value for dimension , I have given value like this
[I have attached screen shot dimen folder please check this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EfoFU.png)

I have make the value folder like

```
value
dimen.xml
<dimen name="padding_1">1dp</dimen>
```

and

```
values-sw320dp-hdpi
dminen.xml
 <dimen name="padding_1">what padding should I give</dimen>

values-sw320dp-xhdpi
dminen.xml
 <dimen name="padding_1">what padding should I give</dimen>

values-sw320dp-xxhdpi
dminen.xml
 <dimen name="padding_1">what padding should I give</dimen>

values-sw360dp
dminen.xml
 <dimen name="padding_1">what padding should I give</dimen>

values-sw480dp
dminen.xml
 <dimen name="padding_1">what padding should I give</dimen>

values-sw600dp
dminen.xml
 <dimen name="padding_1">what padding should I give</dimen>

values-sw720dp
dminen.xml
 <dimen name="padding_1">what padding should I give</dimen>
```

My question is that what padding dimension should I give so I can support to different different device, like how to find the 1dp for every value folder.

I have go through with this link
https://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/screens.html

but not understand clearly. I have gone through the `Dimenify` plugin as well but not getting clear solution.

**Edit**
I wanted to know is there any way to put exact dimension in all value bucket or 
any dp converter which convert exact dimension for all value bucket in android

Comment: I'd advise you to read [this part](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) of the official documentation. 

And your dimensions should be named based on what they are used for (e.g. "main_title_margin_top") and not on their value.

Except if you **really** have issues or want a particular design for a screen size, you don't need to create as many dimens.xml files as screen sizes supported.

Comment: @Eselfar thanks for reply , but my question is that there is any tool in android which convert the the dimension for all value bucket, like If I am using 1 dp in values-sw320dp, then dimension will be use in value-sw480dp

Comment: That's the purpose of using dot pixel (dp) instead of pixels (px). It's supposed to automatically adjust based on the screen. If your screen A is 10" and 1280x720px and your screen B is 5" and 1920x1080px, 1 dp on screen A is gonna be different than screen B. That why in most of the cases you need to specify the size you want only once, and then it's automagically managed by the system. There are issues sometimes on tablet as they have a sh*tty ratio, so you have to create an other dimens.xml file for large screen. But that's all. It's explained on the page I linked in my previous comment.

Answer (score 1):

```
values folders to create

values-sw320dp,
values-sw480dp,
values-sw600dp, 
values-sw720dp. You should create dimens.xml in all the values folders.

values-sw360dp
dimens.xml
<dimen name="padding_1">5dp</dimen>

values-sw480dp
dimens.xml
<dimen name="padding_1">8dp</dimen>

values-sw600dp
dimens.xml
<dimen name="padding_1">10dp</dimen>

values-sw720dp
dminen.xml
<dimen name="padding_1">13dp</dimen>

Based on your requirement you can give padding or any dimen values. As you 
given, you should give same name for dimen in all the folders. Android will 
automatically pick the dimen value based on your screen size.
```

Comment: @MinnnuKaAnae I wanted to know how  to get the all dimension for all value folder like 2 dp, 3 dp, ..... and all , is there any formula for that or any tool to get this dimension

Comment: you no need to worry about all dimensions, for ex, in your xml one edittext is there for that you have given dimens like android:padding="@dimen/padding_1", android will pick automatically all the dimensions you mentioned with padding_1 for different screen sizes

Comment: but I wanted to know how to put the all dimension dp in different different folder

Comment: have you created different layouts folder to support multi screens.

Comment: for that no formula is there, you have to given according to your requirement by seeing the layout in preview

Comment: like we use mdpi: 1.0 (base density) hdpi: 1.5,xhdpi: 2.0,xxhdpi: 3.0,xxxhdpi: 4.0.  So how should I define the density for all value folder

Answer (score 0):

A few tips to help you go with your answer.

The dp metric lets you define consistent sizes across device densities.
This would typically mean they look the exact same size on a majority of devices.

While giving a fixed width works for a few of the cases, visual appeal truly lies in the fact that you can scale down the size of your UI on smaller devices and scale it up on higher devices. You need to start using android's bucketing feature that pulls out different resources based on the device config with the same qualifying name.

Lets say you may choose for eg. to have margins

a `margin_normal` maybe visually perfect at 16dp for xxhdpi, but you see that 18dp works for xxxhdpi whereas 14dp works for xhdpi device.
These are subjective values but rest assured scale factors are a good approximation to this rule.

[Dimenify](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9349-dimenify) deals with this conversion automatically but you need to provide the scale factors by trial and error and as a one time effort.